# Android lifecycle observers don't trigger when code is minified by R8

Tags: android, proguard, android-lifecycle, androidx, android-r8

When i build my code with `minifyEnabled=true` then lifecycle observers don't trigger on any events.

```
lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY)
    @Keep
    fun anyEvent(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
        // Never triggers
        Timber.i("Source=%s, event=%s", source, event)
    }
})
```

`androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle` with version `2.2.0-rc01` (previous versions may be affected too).

The `compileSdkVersion` is `28` and I'm testing on an Android 10 (API29) emulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After about 4 hours I can answer this myself and I hope this keeps someone else from despairing.

R8 removes some necessary callbacks. I painstakingly went through everything and narrowed it down to these missing:

```
20745,20751d20744
< androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$1
<     public void onActivityPostCreated(android.app.Activity,android.os.Bundle)
<     public void onActivityPostStarted(android.app.Activity)
<     public void onActivityPostResumed(android.app.Activity)
<     public void onActivityPrePaused(android.app.Activity)
<     public void onActivityPreStopped(android.app.Activity)
<     public void onActivityPreDestroyed(android.app.Activity)
27034,27037d27026
< androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener
<     public abstract void onCreate()
<     public abstract void onStart()
<     public abstract void onResume()
```

The issue is only present if you compile against API 28, but run your code on API 29.

There is an open issue ticket on this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142778206

To fix this you can either use `compileSdkVersion 29` or include the following proguard rules:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends androidx.lifecycle.EmptyActivityLifecycleCallbacks { *; }
-keepclassmembers class androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already fixed in revision lifecycle version 2.2.0-rc02

For more details :- 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0-rc02

Comment: Can't make it work with sdk version 29 and android 9 device.